# Ocaml: error type

Tags: ocaml

Can someone explain why i have error in this code ?

It take 2 list a1, a2, a3 ... and b1 b2 b3 ... to produce a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3 ...

but error appears

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         int list
```

example of use: `append [1; 2; 3] [4; 5; 6];;`
this is the code:

```
let rec append a b = 
if List.length a == 0 && List.length b == 0
then
[]
else
(List.hd a :: List.hd b) :: append (List.tl a) (List.tl b);;
```

this should work properly, but it doesn't... How can I fix it ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a precedence problem. You can't write like this:

```
(1 :: 2) :: []
```

The right hand operand of `::` must be a list.

You have to write like this:

```
1 :: (2 :: [])
```

If you remove the parentheses around `(List.hd a :: List.hd b)` you should get past this problem.

As a side comment, it would be more idiomatic to use pattern matching than List.length, List.hd, and List.tl.

What is your code supposed to do if the lists are different lengths?